# Can't access method defined in parent class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, methods, parent-child

I am attempting to use the method `is_word_in()` from `TitleTrigger`'s parent class `WordTrigger` but I am getting a `NameError` saying `is_word_is` is not defined. I feel like I am missing a key concept of inheritance, how can I correct this?

```
class NewsStory(object):
    def __init__(self, guid, title, subject, summary, link):
        self.guid = guid
        self.title = title
        self.subject = subject
        self.summary = summary
        self.link = link
    def get_guid(self):
        return self.guid
    def get_title(self):
        return self.title
    def get_subject(self):
        return self.subject
    def get_summary(self):
        return self.summary
    def get_link(self):
        return self.link

class WordTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word.lower()
    def is_word_in(self, text):
        words = text.split(' ')
        for word in words:
            word.strip(string.punctuation).lower()
            if self.word == word:
                return True
        return False

class TitleTrigger(WordTrigger):
    def __init__(self, word):
        WordTrigger.__init__(self, word)
    def evaluate(self, story):
        self.title = story.get_title()
        if is_word_in(self.title):
            return True
        return False

trigger = TitleTrigger('Soft')
trigger.evaluate(NewsStory('', 'I prefer pillows that are soft.', '', '', ''))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the function incorrectly, you will need to invoke it with `self`:

```
if self.is_word_in(self.title):
   ^^^^^
```

Note the additional `self.` before the `is_word_in`, which is used to tell that you mean the method of the instance.

Comment: What is the effect when self is not used? What is it trying to access then?

Comment: @Jordan if self is not present, python would try finding an object named with is_word_in within the method you are calling it in, which obviously gives the error.

Comment: Ah! Makes complete sense now, thank you very much :)